# Can I simply replace my Windows 10 File History drive with a larger one and retain the existing file history?

Tags: windows-10, file-history

I'm planning to upgrade my Windows 10 Pro system's 2TB HDD used for Windows File History to a 3TB HDD but I understand that it's not just a matter of copying the contents of the existing 2TB disk to the 3TB disk and then removing the 2TB disk and replacing it with the 3TB disk that uses the same drive letter.

Can anyone please advise how I should proceed? I don't want to lose the existing file history on the existing disk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you clone the drive onto the new one then it should get the disk signature from the old one, so Windows will regard it as the same one. You may need to go into Disk Management to extend the new disk into the available space after the cloning. You won't be able to have both disks connected to the same system at the same time as that would cause a disk signature collision.

I did pretty much the same thing recently going from a 1 TB disk to a 2 TB disk—I use Macrium Reflect Home for backups, so I was able to restore the backup onto the new drive, and my File History has continued over the change as far as I can tell. I use the paid-for version, but there is also a free version and plenty of other disk cloning software around.

The procedure was basically:

- Stop File History.
- Backup the 1 TB drive.
- Shut down Win10.
- Swap the drive for the 2 TB.
- Restore the backed-up 1 TB drive to the 2 TB drive.
- Restart File History.
- Go into Disk Management to extend the disk into the whole of the capacity.

N.B. It needs to be a drive backup, not just a data backup.

As always, the advice is to make sure you have a backup of your data before doing any disk manipulation. Be prepared for it to take several hours.

Comment: So did you backup the 1TB drive, stop File History, shutdown Win10, swap the drive for the 2TB, set the 2TB drive letter to be the same as the 1TB that was removed, then restore the backed up 1TB drive to the 2TB drive, then restart File History?

Comment: @endurium Yes, exactly. I had forgotten that I stopped and later restarted File History, thank you for that reminder, I'll update my answer to make it more accurate. *Except* you don't do the drive letter thing, the cloning process does that in Macrium Reflect when you restore it from the backup. Other backup/cloning software may behave differently; I can only relate what I actually did.

Comment: Thanks @andrewmorton the steps in your revised answer did the trick.  Worth mentioning: if you restore the disk image to a larger drive extend the size of the partition to make use of the extra space, make sure that in doing so you don't remove the 15-16MB hidden partition which I believe File History creates to register/identify the drive.  The Paragon Hard Disk Manager Pro software I used to backup, restore and resize the disk partition gave me the option to optimise the partition resize but a preview of the operation (very useful!) showed that the hidden partition would be removed.

Comment: @endurium Was there any indication that anything was using that tiny partition? I always thought that tiny partitions were used for aligning the partition boundaries to some multiple of something.

Comment: there was no indication of anything using that partition, but I didn't want to take the chance.